# Java Script : get the string equivalent of a elements ID

Tags: javascript, html, spring-mvc

my naming convention

```
id=xxxxx //actual field shown in the screen
id=xxxxxHDN // hidden field containing the enable/disabled status of the component from the set from the controller.
```

Now what I am trying to do is get the satus of xxxxxHDN to be true/false , 
and accordingly set the components status to disabled /enabled .with java script..

```
var div = document.getElementById("hiddenFields"); // i hava some 30 hidden fields       containing the 
var j;
    for (j=0;j<div.childNodes.length;j++)
if(div.childNodes[j].value){
    alert("inside the loop");
    var someElementHDN = div.childNodes[j].id;     // my aim is to get the ID=xxxxxHDN
    var someElementHDNToString = someElementHDN .toString(); // my aim is to get the string value "xxxxxHDN"
    var toRemove = 'HDN'; // the part i wanna remove from 'someElementHDNToString' to make it an id for 'xxxxx'
    var equivalantComponentIDAsString = someElementToString.replace(toRemove,'');
    $('#' + equivalantComponentIDAsString ).attr('disabled', true);
    }
}
```

Invested a lot of time manupulatiing things above , doesent seems to work . I am new to java scrcript , Where am I missing it?

Comment: Why this magic number 10 used to initialize the loop variable j?

Comment: Ramesh Thats a miss ,while I was debugging ,for not to get in the loop for multiple times while  , I will edit the question , thank you

Comment: @Ramesh Looks like he already is (last two lines of the loop).

Comment: In which browser does a DIV element have a length attribute?

Comment: Where does `someElement` come from? If it's a DOM element, where is the `toString` method in the DOM [HTMLElement interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#htmlelement)? Only a small number of elements have a `value` attribute, what type of elements are you dealing with?

Comment: @Peter Wilkison : my mistake , i edited ..

Comment: var div = document.getElementById("hiddenFields");  therse are hidden fields simple hidden fields decleared as

Comment: <pre><form:hidden
  path="unrestricted1AMTHDN" id="unrestricted1AMTHDN" /></pre>

Comment: Can I suggest fixing syntax errors and other simple mistakes in your code before posting? e.g. i++ when i doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your posted js code has error: div does not have a "length", do you mean "div.childNodes.length"?
Anyway, since you're using jQuery already, I think it can become easier as below:
Already tested and it works fine.

```
$("#hiddenFields input[type='hidden'][id$='HDN']").each(
    function () {
        var elemId = this.id.replace(/HDN$/, '');
        $('#' + elemId).attr('disabled', this.value.toLowerCase() == 'false' ? false : true);
    }
);
```

Comment: Hi Teddy, your code is not taking care of problem such as HDN repeating more than once in the hidden field ID

Comment: @Ramesh Hi, be aware that "id$='HDN'" means only to find those ends with HDN, same as the regular expression "/HDN$/". So it's already able to handle the repeating case.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an element with id like 'fooHDN' and want to find another element with id 'foo', then you can do something like:

```
var otherElement = document.getElementById(someElement.id.replace(/HDN$/,''));
```

Assuming that you already have `someElement` and it's a DOM element.